# Shared memory stuff in cpp dll

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

Soft MetaTrader 5. It's trading terminal. It's "indicator" windows are little cpp-like programs. They can load pure cpp dlls. Every "indicator" works in separate thread. 
I need to create shared memory stuff which can be accessable from every "indicator". Also for shared memory could be loaded in every indicator it must be in particular dll.

I found info about boost interprocesses.

I am newbee with boost and multithreading. 
So I wonder am I right way?

1. Create dll with shared memory functionality and interface to access it from indicator.
2. Load dll in several "indicators".
3. Access it from several "indicators" in real-time?

Could you also advice other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variables in shared libraries are not shared across the library user processes. That segment of data is created for every process which loads the library, only the read-only code segment is actually shared.

You need to use a library for shared memory, such as `boost::interprocess shared_memory_object` or `POSIX Shared Memory`, or Qt's `QSharedMemory`. That is however in case you need inter-process communication.

There is nothing special you need to do in order for multiple threads to access shared memory in the same process, aside from using a mutex to prevent data races.